# Combine two complex regular expressions with or?

Tags: regex

I have two complex regex that do two parts of the same task. As a result, I'm basically double-working - one pass with rex A, and one pass with rex B. I would like to combine the two using `| (or)` so it's knocked out in one shot.

Can rex marry the two?

- Rex A, is true for strings that are wrapped in matching, js-commented md5's. 
  EG: `/*a1700e65a69859ac8c56b0baef91b61a*/this text, as well as the enclosing comments will be matched. There may or may not be a new line between this string and the closing md5/*a1700e65a69859ac8c56b0baef91b61a*/`

  ```
  (\/\*(.){32}\*\/).*(\n)?\1
  ```
- Rex B performs similarly, but for html-stlye comments 
  EG: `<!--a1700e65a69859ac8c56b0baef91b61a-->text-text-text<!--a1700e65a69859ac8c56b0baef91b61a-->`

  ```
  (<!--(.*)-->).*(\n)?\1
  ```

**Things I tried:**

```
// simple or. this ignores the latter of the or
(\/\*(.){32}\*\/).*(\n)?\1|(<!--(.){32}-->).*(\n)?\1
// thinking it may have been greedy, i switched it. No real change in behavior 
(<!--(.){32}-->).*(\n)?\1|(\/\*(.){32}\*\/).*(\n)?\1
```

Rather than `RexA|RexB`, I tried putting the switch inside the capture group. This seemed to have a similar effect. It would match either of the content between the matching comments, but seemed to exclude the enclosing comments that wrap it.

```
((\/\*)|(<!--)(.){32}(\*\/)|(-->)).*(\n)?\1
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/lE3bI7/) is a regex101 demo.

Any tips?

Comment: Do you have test cases? Perhaps even a [regex101](http://regex101.com)?

Comment: Attempting to search and replace malware in order to clean your system is deeply, troublingly misdirected. You should restore from version control or known-good backups. See one of the many, many duplicate questions for more-detailed rationale.

Comment: The two base patterns are false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580625/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency

Comment: @tripleee I couldn't agree with you more, and that would *absolutely* be the best way about it. In my dream scenario: "200 sites are hacked? eh. merge origin and call it good." Sadly, I'm not in that kind of situation here :( (second week with this company)

Comment: @ShawnMehan [here it is](https://regex101.com/r/lE3bI7/2)

Comment: Note the capturing group numbers in the regex101 Explanation pane. Per my answer below, you do need to change the final `1` to `4` and you're all right.

Comment: You also don't need the extra non-capturing `(?:)` wrappers.

Comment: Sounds like good dailywtf material...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of the captured group is counted from the left, counting left parentheses of captured groups. By my count, that means the final `\1` in (both) your `|` attempt should instead be `\4` perhaps?

Comment: Shown in [this version](https://regex101.com/r/lE3bI7/4), this one seems to have done it! `(<!--(.){32}-->).*(\n)?\1|(\/\*(.){32}\*\/).*(\n)?\4` **edit:** just now tried it in a real use-case, and this nails it. Learned something new about how capture groups are counted :)

Answer (score 2):

How about just wrapping each in a non-capturing group `(?:)` with an alternate `|` in the middle?

```
(?:(\/\*(.){32}\*\/).*(\n)?\1)|(?:(<!--(.*)-->).*(\n)?\1)
```